# What's the difference between Apache Commons Bag and Guava MultiSet?

Tags: java, apache-commons, guava

It seems that those two are exactly same, any confirms?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Primarily this: Multiset follows the Collection contract precisely, and generally plays better with other JDK collections utilities.  Additionally, Multiset has generics support, supports the entrySet() method, and the setCount method, none of which appear to be offered by Bag.

They serve the same purpose, as you can clearly tell, but I'd like to think that Multiset wins in most respects.